# Error mounting a micro SD card

Tags: 16.04, micro-sd

This is the error message:

```
Error mounting /dev/mmcblk0 at /media/jonathan/bb960ee6-cd2a-476b-999c-7a929d0e26dd: Command-line `mount -t "ext4" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/mmcblk0" "/media/jonathan/bb960ee6-cd2a-476b-999c-7a929d0e26dd"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: mount /dev/mmcblk0 on /media/jonathan/bb960ee6-cd2a-476b-999c-7a929d0e26dd failed: Structure needs cleaning
```

I'm pretty new with Ubuntu and I appreciate any help its a 32 GB micro SD card I have tried a USB card reader and an internal one I'm running 14.04.(correction 16.04)

Comment: Do you have any files in the micro sd that want to keep or is it ok to format it? Install gnome-disk-utility (disks) and see if it recognizes the device.

Comment: i clicked format disk then set it to no partitioning and then added a partition it works now thank you for all of the help

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept it. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)